# Change the font size on the page for selected classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
function czcionka_zmien_rozmiar(punktow) {
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
        var rozmiar = style.getPropertyValue('font-size');
        rozmiar = rozmiar.replace("px", "");
        rozmiar = rozmiar * 1;
        rozmiar = rozmiar + punktow;
        e.style.fontSize = rozmiar + "px";
        localStorage.setItem("rozmiar", rozmiar);
    }

    function czcionka_ustaw_zapisany_rozmiar() {
        var rozmiar = localStorage.getItem("rozmiar");
        if (rozmiar!==null) {
            var e = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
            e.style.fontSize = rozmiar + "px";
        }
    }


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", czcionka_ustaw_zapisany_rozmiar);
```

This feature increases the font size on the page. I would like to do it so that it would be enlarged or reduced the font for the following classes: .tresc, .tytul, .opis. How to do it?

Currently, classes .tresc, .tytul, and .opis have different sizes (written in PX).

Answer (score 0):

So, what I've understood from your question is that you want a bigger font size for certain classes. I'm not sure if you want it get bigger dynamically, but I've prepared the code assuming you do.

CSS:

```
.changed-font{
  fontSize: 15px //assuming 15px is bigger than what you currently have
}
```

Javascript:

```
function changeClass(classname,element)
{ 
     element.classList.add(classname);
}
function czcionka_zmien_rozmiar(punktow) {
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
        var rozmiar = style.getPropertyValue('font-size');
        changeClass("changed-font",e) 
}
```

Now if you want to change to a dynamic value, then the class name doesn't really matter.

If you only meant to alter your functions to handle your classes `.tresc, .tytul, and .opis` then you only need to change:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
```

To:

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName(".tresc")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you use the `localStorage`, but here is what I'll do:

- Add a new parameter for "classname" in your function (or a copy of the function),
- Add `classname` management to change the `font-size` of all corresponding elements using a `forEach` loop.

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

Snippet:

```js
function czcionka_zmien_rozmiar(punktow, classname) {
  // punktow management
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
  var rozmiar = style.getPropertyValue('font-size');
  rozmiar = rozmiar.replace("px", "");
  rozmiar = +rozmiar + punktow;

  // classname management
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);
  Array.from(els).forEach((el) => {
    el.style.fontSize = rozmiar + "px";
  });
}

// Call the function
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", czcionka_zmien_rozmiar(0, "tresc"));
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", czcionka_zmien_rozmiar(6, "tytul"));
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", czcionka_zmien_rozmiar(12, "opis"));
```

```html
<p class="tresc">tresc</p>
<p class="tytul">tytul</p>
<p class="opis">opis</p>
```